# How can I solve this continuity question?

Tags: calculus, inequality, continuity

Basically, I am trying to understand this problem, but I still have not gotten how to solve it, nor the steps to lead me to the answer. Could anyone help me out? Thanks.
Question: What value should be assigned to K to make f continuous at x = 0 [Here is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dufLx.png)

Comment: How much is $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}x$ ?

Comment: What value should be assigned to K to make f continuous at x = 0

Comment: Please ponder my hint.

Comment: Sorry. The value equals to 1.

Comment: So, why did I ask you that ?

Comment: Do you want to get the problem equal to sinx/x?

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous at some point $a$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$. Just compute, in your case, the previous limite, compare it to $f(0)$ and draw your conclusions.

Also, I must say that this forum is not the proper way of dealing with such a basic question. If you are not able to solve this question, you must really study and look at some examples before anything else.